# How do I looping through mutiple lines and tokenizing, returning an array containing all the tokens?

Tags: c, tokenize

I posted a (terrible formatted and lackluster) question earlier asking about how I can pass an array as an input parameter and return that modified array. After some more messing around I found out that the function works fine for single line input, but starts to have problems when the file contains multiple lines separated by newline.

I appreciate any suggestions on how to improve my code (and posts) in general. Thank you.

The code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LEN 1000

const char delimiter[] = " \t\r\n\v\f";

void tokenize(char *string, char *ret[MAX_LINE_LEN]) {
    char *ptr;
    ptr = strtok(string, delimiter);
    int i = 0;
    while (ptr != NULL) {
        ret[i] = ptr;
        i++;
        ptr = strtok(NULL, delimiter);
    }
}

int main(void) {
    char line[MAX_LINE_LEN];
    static char *temparr[MAX_LINE_LEN] = {0};

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
        tokenize(line, temparr);
    }

    int i = 0;
    while (temparr[i]) {
        printf("%s\n", temparr[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

For input:

```
There was nothing else to do. 
The deed had already been done and there was no going back. 
It now had been become a question of how they were going to be able to get out of this situation and escape.
```

The output is seemingly correct:

```
There
was
nothing
else
to
do.
The
deed
had
already
been
done
and
there
was
no
going
back.
It
now
had
been
become
a
question
of
how
they
were
going
to
be
able
to
get
out
of
this
situation
and
escape.
```

But when each line is separated by newline:

```
There was nothing else to do. 
The deed had already been done and there was no going back. 
It now had been become a question of how they were going to be able to get out of this situation and escape.
```

It only returns a tokenized array of the last line:

```
It
now
had
been
become
a
question
of
how
they
were
going
to
be
able
to
get
out
of
this
situation
and
escape.
```

And when the last line is short:

```
There was nothing else to do. 
The deed had already been done and there was no going back. 
It now had been become a question of how they were going to be able to 
get out of this situation and escape.
```

The return array is:

```
get
out
of
this
situation
and
escape.
pe.

they
were
going
to
be
able
to
```

I assume I went wrong somewhere with looping the fgets() function, but I'm not sure why or how to proceed to get the first output. I've tried including "\n" as one of the delimiters, but it didn't seem to do anything.
I've also been told that strtok() is unsafe (not thread-safe, modifies the original string,...). I'm not sure how this plays in here, but what are the alternatives?

(Test paragraph is taken from https://randomwordgenerator.com/paragraph.php)

Comment: Please explain your `main` function in great detail to a [rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) or suitable substitute (like a friend). When do you read? When do you print?

Comment: Another problem is that if you tokenize a line that is shorter than the previous line, then you will not "reset" the destination array and its pointers.

Comment: @thestranger, Notice that `tokenize()` has `int i = 0;` causes each call to put tokens starting a index 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

- the array of token pointers has a defined length of `MAX_LINE_LEN`, which is somewhat confusing. Use a more telling name such as `MAX_TOKEN_COUNT`. Similarly, if `MAX_LINE_LEN` is the maximum line length, the input buffer should have at least 2 extra bytes for the newline and the null terminator.
- you must allocate memory for each token, otherwise all token pointers point to places in the input buffer, leading to incorrect output as observed.
- you should pass the initial index where to append the tokens and the array length to avoid writing beyond its boundaries.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LEN 1000
#define MAX_TOKEN_COUNT 1000

const char delimiter[] = " \t\r\n\v\f";

size_t tokenize(char *str, char *ret[], size_t i, size_t n) {
    char *ptr;
    while (i < n && (ptr = strtok(str, delimiter)) != NULL) {
        ret[i] = strdup(ptr);
        i++;
        str = NULL;
    }
    return i;
}

int main(void) {
    char line[MAX_LINE_LEN + 2];
    char *temparr[MAX_TOKEN_COUNT];
    size_t n = 0;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin)) {
        n = tokenize(line, temparr, n, MAX_TOKEN_COUNT);
    }

    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", temparr[i]);
    }
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        free(temparr[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the same buffer for multiple lines of input. The buffer will be overwritten by each new line of entry, making previously assigned pointers invalid. You need to either define a finite collection of buffers (limited), or use "heap storage".

New to C? Perhaps new to the concept of "dynamic memory".

The objective seems to be to "buffer up" input from `stdin` until EOF is reached. You could simply accumulate all the input and *tokenise* only at the end:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LINE_LEN 1000

int main(void) {
    char line[MAX_LINE_LEN]; // a single input buffer
    char *lines = NULL;
    size_t current = 0;

    while( fgets( line, sizeof line, stdin ) ) {
        size_t len = strlen( line );
        char *p = realloc( lines, current + len + 1 ); // growing storage of text input
        if( p == NULL ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "realloc failed\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        lines = p; // update to point to grown block
        memcpy( lines + current, line, len ); // preserve this line of input
        current += len; // adjust offset to keep track of end
    }
    if( lines == NULL ) // Nothing entered?
        return 0;

    lines[ current ] = '\0'; // terminate making entire block a single C string

    // Below is a "tokenising" mill growing an array of pointers as needed.
    const char delimiter[] = " \t\r\n\v\f";
    char *pArr = NULL;
    size_t i = 0;
    for( char *cp = lines; ( cp = strtok( cp, delimiter ) ) != NULL; cp = NULL ) {
        char **p = realloc( pArr, (i + 2) * sizeof *p ); // notice "+ 2" for NULL also
        if( p == NULL ) {
            fprintf( stderr, "realloc failed\n" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }
        pArr = p;
        pArr[ i++ ] = cp; // store this token
    }
    if( pArr == NULL ) { // Mischievous user entered ONLY whitespace!!
        free( lines );
        return 0;
    }

    pArr[ i++ ] = NULL; // terminate array of pointers with a NULL.

    for( i = 0; pArr[i]; i++ ) // Loop outputting tokens until NULL (end)
        puts( pArr[i] );

    free( pArr ); // release array of ptrs
    free( lines ); // release buffer of text

    return 0;
}
```

This should be self explanatory. If there is anything you don't understand, please ask in a comment below.

---

"*what are the alternatives?*"

`strtok()` is fine for a simple application such as this. It's younger brother `strtok_r()` does not maintain, internally, the **state** of the tokenising. `strtok_r()` should be used in multithreaded applications, or when you want to "sub-tokenise" strings. For instance, you could tokenise on '\n' to extract one sentence at a time from your buffer, then tokenise on each word in that sentence using other whitespace characters.

Another alternative is to develop your own version of `strtok()`, perhaps using `strspn()` and `strcspn()` to quickly locate delimiter characters. Doing so allows you to decide if you want to *clobber* delimiters as `strtok()` does.

Beware: `strtok()` considers consecutive delimiters to be a single instance. It will not return a pointer to an empty string. Eg: "a,b,,,c" will be treated as if it were "a,b,c".

---

Homework: refactor this single function, separating 'input', 'tokenisation' and 'printing' into their own functions with appropriate parameters and return values.

Comment: Nitpicking: `lines` is somewhat confusing as it is not an array of lines... maybe `text` would better convey the intent.

Comment: May I have my meal now? (while enjoying a bit of recommended music...) :-)